# Query documents that have different sub-fields heterogeneous

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a collection containing documents of two different (but similar) structures, some have field "someField" with a single string value, others have field "someField" with a bunch of sub-fields.

Can I query the following two types of documents, get someField as a string when it is a string, and as *some of the sub fields* if it has sub fields? (It's easy enough to get either the string or *all* of the sub fields)

Bonus points if you can format the sub-fields to look like the single string documents.

Collection containing two types of document (simplified example)

```js
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("53345585cdf2fb6a03f4a7bc"),
    "document" : {
        "someField" : "Foo 1, Bar 2",
    }
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("533455sdfghjfb6a03f4a7bc"),
    "document" : {
        "someField" : {
            "foo": "1",
            "bar": "2",
            "wibble": "I don't want this field"
        }
    }
}
```

Extra Information:

The best I have so far is to use two queries, and join the results together afterwards in another script or code:

```json
db.someCollection.find(
    {
        "document.someField.foo":{$exists:false},
    },
    {
        "document.someField": 1,
        _id: 0 
    }
).forEach(printjson)

db.someCollection.find(
    {
        "document.someField.foo":{$exists:true},
    },
    {
        "document.someField.foo": 1,
        "document.someField.bar": 1,
        _id: 0 
    }
).forEach(printjson)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is a little abstract but you can work this sort of solution using [**`.aggregate()`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/) and the [**`$project`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) operator:

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
    { "$project": {
        "onefield": { "$cond": [
            "$document.someField.foo",
            {
                "foo": "$document.someField.foo",
                "bar": "$document.someField.bar"
            },
            "$document.someField"
        ]}
    }}
])
```

This also makes use of the ternary [**`$cond`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/) operator in order to "evaluate" how the results are going to look.

So where your items **do** have the *sub-document* field then you can "re-shape" to the fields you want. When they **do not** then you can just dump the field as is shown **or** ( if your logic requires it ) nest further [**`$cond`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/) operations to determine what to do with the field.

And of course if you really want everything as a string then use [**`$concat`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/concat/) to do this instead:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    { "$project": {
        "onefield": { "$cond": [
            "$document.someField.foo",
            { "$concat": [
                "Foo ",
                "$document.someField.foo",
                " ,Bar ",
                "$document.someField.bar"
            ]},
            "$document.someField"
        ]}
    }}
])
```

Answer (score 0):

I Think [@Neil-Lunn's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22760898/66293) is probably better (I'm still working to convert it to my real world example), but I managed to do it myself using a JS function. *simplified from my real-world, so may contain typos.

```js
db.someCollection.find()
    .forEach(function(o) {
        if(o.document.someField.foo) {
            print("Foo " 
                + o.document.someField.foo 
                + ", Bar "
                + o.document.someField.bar
            );
        } else {
            print(o.document.someField);
        }
    }
)
```

The condition checks if foo exists (undefined is false), and then does some manual string concatenation when necessary.

Comment: You can always ask another question for you "real world" example. If the data you are working with is large then you would want to do this transformation without iterating. I must have missed that you **wanted** strings, so I updated that part as well.